# Collect throwables for all CompletableFuture.allOf

Tags: java, asynchronous, promise, java-8

Crazy thing is going on. I have batch of parallel async tasks and each one may throw an exception. I want to execute all of them and to *collect* all possible exceptions and wrap it with just one exception. But it looks that collected `Throwable` object may get **deleted** (!?), like it is referenced by a weak reference. It's better to explain this on example.

### Example

Here is the full source of an example. I will split it here in logical parts, to explain it better what I am trying to do. Just merge all bellow code blocks in your IDE if you want to try it.

#### main

We call the `process()` and pass input data - array of integers that are going to be processed. We check for exceptions and then list all *collected* exceptions.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class CollectExceptions {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CompletableFuture<List<Integer>> futures =
                process(Arrays.asList("1", "a", "b", "4"));

        try {
            futures.get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            BatchException batchException = (BatchException) e.getCause();
            Stream.of(batchException.exceptions).forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }
```

#### process

First, we convert input `Iterable` to `CompletableFuture<Integer>[]`. This means that each work over single input is passed to the `supplyAsync`. Since we want to collect errors, we use `handle` method. Please note that the same thing happens with `exeptionally()` and `whenComplete()`.

Then we compose a `CompletableFuture` of all input futures. When that one is complete, i.e. when all input is processed, we decide should be throw an exception; if any exception is collected.

```
public static CompletableFuture<List<Integer>> process(Iterable<String> documents) {
    final List<Throwable> throwables = new ArrayList<>();

    CompletableFuture<Integer>[] allFuturesArray = StreamSupport
        .stream(documents.spliterator(), false)
        .map((document) -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> workSync(document)).handle((list, t) -> {
            if (t != null) {
                throwables.add(t);
            }
            return list;
        }))
        .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);

    CompletableFuture<Void> allDoneFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(allFuturesArray);

    return allDoneFuture
        .thenApply(v -> Stream.of(allFuturesArray)
            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
            .collect(Collectors.<Integer>toList())
        )
        .whenComplete((list, throwable) -> {
            if (throwables.size() > 0) {
                throw new BatchException(throwables);
            }
        });
}
```

#### work

Here is the working method. We added some delay since otherwise you would not see the problem. There is also definition of `BatchException` that simply store input exceptions.

```
    public static Integer workSync(String string) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Integer.valueOf(string);
    }

    public static class BatchException extends RuntimeException {
        public final Throwable[] exceptions;
        public BatchException(Iterable<Throwable> exceptions) {
            this.exceptions = StreamSupport
                .stream(exceptions.spliterator(), false)
                .toArray(Throwable[]::new);
        }
    } 
}
```

### Execution and the issue

Program behaves inconsistently! When I run it from my IDE (in DEBUG mode), i see that there are 2 exceptions, but *SOMETIMES* one of this exceptions is `null`!!!

Here is one output:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java....
null
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"
done
```

Wow! WTF? How come we have `null` collected??? It looks that some UNSAFE work is being done inside.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"It looks that some UNSAFE work is being done inside."

Yeah ... Your `throwables` list access is unsynchronized :)